# Editing TYPO3 news items in the tx_news administration panel doesn't work

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I'm in the process of migrating from TYPO3 version 7.6.X to 8.7.X (with plans to upgrade further). Everything relatively works except the functionality regarding the tx_news plugin. Editing news items in the news administration panel doesn't work. When clicking on a news title in News Administration panel, TYPO3 doesn't perform any action. By right-clicking on the news icon and selecting edit you can edit, similar to editing with the 'pencil' from the list view.

The link generated by the system looks correct and is active:

> typo3/index.php?M=web_NewsTxNewsM2&moduleToken=b983b05ca6050a0d7bb6b05598b81489f118c23e&id=123#

I noticed that linking stops working after upgrading the tx_news to version 7.0.0 minimum

My configuration:

- TYPO3 8.7
- PHP 7.3.33
- tx_news 7.3.1

Thanks in advance for any help.